# How to deal with cross-thread access exceptions?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

A common exception one can get when working with multiple threads in WPF is:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

What are the options to deal with this properly?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Depending on the situation there are various options:

**Accessing a control from another thread**

<sup>e.g. updating a TextBlock with progress information.</sup>

- **[Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx):**

  In this case the easiest thing you can do is avoiding the direct interaction with the control. You can just [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) the property you want to access or modify to an object whose class [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and then set the property on that object instead. The framework will handle the rest for you. (In general you rarely should need to interact with UI-elements directly, you can almost always bind the respective properties and work with the binding source instead; one case where direct control access may be necessary is control authoring.)

  There are some cases where data binding alone is not enough, for example when trying to modify a bound [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), for this you need...
- **[Dispatching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx):**

  You can dispatch your accessing code to the thread owning the object, this can be done by calling [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) or [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) on the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) owning the object being accessed (getting this `Dispatcher` is possible on another thread).

  e.g.

  ```
  new Thread(ThisThreadStart).Start();
  ```

  ```
  void ThisThreadStart()
  {
      textBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => textBlock.Text = "Test"));
  }
  ```

  If it is not clear on which thread a method is executed you can use [`Dispatcher.CheckAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) to either dispatch or execute an action directly.

  e.g.

  ```
  void Update()
  {
      Action action = () => myTextBlock.Text = "Test";
      var dispatcher = myTextBlock.Dispatcher;
      if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
          action();
      else
          dispatcher.Invoke(action);
  }
  ```

  If an object is not a [`DispatcherObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx) and you still need the associated `Dispatcher` you can use [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx) *in the thread creating the object* (so doing this in the method being executed by a thread will not do you any good). For convenience as you usually create objects on the application's main UI thread; you can get that thread's `Dispatcher` from anywhere using `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

*Special cases:*

- [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

  Move any control access to [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) as it occurs on the thread that created the instance (which should of course be the UI-thread)
- Timers

  In WPF you can use the [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) for convenience, it does the dispatching for you so any code in [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx) is invoked on the associated dispatcher. If you can delegate the dispatching to the data binding system you of course can use a normal timer as well.

You can read more about how the `Dispatcher` queue works and WPF threading in general [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

**Accessing an object created on another thread**

<sup>e.g. loading an image in the background.</sup>

If the object in question is not [`Freezable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) you should in general simply *avoid creating it on another thread or restricting access to the creating thread*. If it is `Freezable` you just need to call [`Freeze`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.freeze.aspx) to make it accessible to other threads.

**Accessing a data object from another thread**

That is, the type whose instance is being updated is user-code. If an exception is thrown this situation probably came about by someone using [`DependencyObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) as base type for a data class.

This situation is the same as **accessing a control** and the same approaches can be applied but usually it should be avoided in the first place. Granted, this allows for simple property change notifications via [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) and those properties can also be bound but often enough this is just not worth giving up thread-independency. You can get change notifications from [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and the binding system in WPF is inherently asymmetrical, there always is a property that is bound (target) and something that is the source for this binding. Usually the UI is the target and the data is the source, meaning that only UI components should need dependency properties.

Comment: So here's a dumb question then.  What do you do when Dispatcher.CheckAccess() throws "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"?

Comment: @RogerWillcocks: Never happened to me. Give a complete example reproducing this...

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox.Text = "Test" )); Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That would be several hundred lines of code, for something I "figured out".

But the summary is:

App_OnStartup
generate a background thread

in the callback,

Call

Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() - gets the exception
Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() does not

Comment: The problem is the step `Current.MainWindow`, not `MainWindow.Dispatcher`, so yeah, that's not what i would suggest...

Comment: As I figured out, but given MainWindow and Dispatcher are not null, you would expect that a method intended to tell you if cross thread access is safe would not throw a cross thread exception

Answer (score 0):

I have a udp listener object that communicates through events where the method/callbacks are +='ed in my mainWindow wpf .cs file.

The event handler functions are called with parameters, one being the message I want displayed in a listbox in the mainWindow.cs

Using the information in this thread by H.B. above;
I have added, tested and handled the crossthread in wpf in my eventhandler callback using the following code, but I use a real message not a hard coded one:

```
listBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add("MessageHere")));
```

**UPDATE:**

This is better because you can put more things in the anonymous function.

```
 listBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate 
 {
     listBox1.Items.Add(e.ReaderMessage); 
 });
```