# InvalidOperationException with BackgroundWorker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get a BackgroundWorker to update the UI during program logic execution. But I get the error:

EDIT! So my actual goal, which I guess isn't clear from the sample I provided, is to be able to perform calculations while updating the UI.  See the updated code sample below.

> InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

My C# and xaml follow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        test.Background = Brushes.Orange;

        for (double x = 0; x < 10000000000; )
        {
            x++;
        }

        test.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And then, my XAML:

```
<Button Name="test" Click="test_Click">This is a button!</Button>
```

Comment: Controls may only be accessed by the thread that created them.  Take comfort in the fact that this is actually a good thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with cross-thread access exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923865/how-to-deal-with-cross-thread-access-exceptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the previous lock your app too, try this:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (double x = 0; x < 10000000000; )
        {
            x++;
        }
    }


    private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        test.Background = Brushes.Orange;

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (_,__) =>  test.Background = Brushes.Red; 
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access user interface objects from background threads.  You need to either marshal the call back onto the UI thread (via `Dispatcher.Invoke`) or do the update within a progress or completion event of the `BackgroundWorker`, as these are already run on the UI thread.

That being said, in this case, the BW is *only* updating the UI, so you should just do it directly in your Button's event handler, as there is no other "work" to perform.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { test.Background = Brushes.Orange; }));
}
```

you need to execute it from the UI dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a UI update from the background thread; use either the `RunWorkerCompleted` or the `ProgressChanged` events to update the UI.

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    test.Background = Brushes.Orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in the BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event.  Within this event, you'll need to use the Dispatcher and one of it's 2 main methods: Invoke and BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any code:

```
void CodeToExcecute()
{
        test.Background = Brushes.Orange;

        for (double x = 0; x < 10000000000; )
        {
            x++;
        }

        test.Background = Brushes.Red;

}
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CodeToExcecute() ));
}
```

Comment: ...and completely defeats the purpose of having another thread as it pushes everything back to the UI.

Comment: I think that this is the idea: to separate code logic from visual. Any way, i only had used BackgroundWorker inside MVVM logic, i think that you can modify the properties of ViewModel, and the View get updated (i have to test it).

Answer (score 0):

i have tried some other code, and do some researching, and yes, there exist ways for to modify view from another thread, using the SynchronizationContext.

Please see this example:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
            w.DoWork+=(_, __)=>
                {
                    //sync.Post(p => { button.Content = "Working"; }, null);
                    int j = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        j++;
                        sync.Post(p => { button.Content = j.ToString(); }, null);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    sync.Post(p => { button.Background = Brushes.Aqua; button.Content = "Some Content"; }, null);
                };
            w.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

And this is the view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Some Content" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This code, updates several times the view (a button in this case). I think this solve your initial question.