# The calling thread cannot access this object error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to create dynamically custom userControl in background thread.
This is my method where I am creating new thread:

```
var thread = new Thread(CreateItemInBackgroundThread);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);            
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

And this is method `CreateItemInBackgroundThread`:

```
var uc = new MyUserControl();
UserControl item = uc;
AllControls.Add(item);
//Here I am trying to add control to a current Tab
foreach (var currentTab in _allTabs)
{
    currentTab.DocumentWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                                            {
                                                                if (tab.DocumentWindow.IsSelected)
                                                                {
                                                                    tempTab = tab;
                                                                    tempControl = item;
                                                                    finish = true;
                                                                }

                                                            }));
}
```

This is my finish property

```
bool finish
    {
        get { return _finish; }
        set
        {
            _finish = value;
            if (_finish)
            {
                tempTab.AnimatedCanvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tempTab.AnimatedCanvas.Children.Add(tempControl)));
            }
        } // Here I get error - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
    }
```

How can I avoid this error and why this error happend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923865/how-to-deal-with-cross-thread-access-exceptions

Comment: Also why would you try to use the dispatcher of some specific object? Just use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: I want to access tempControl, , where my dynamically created element is saved and put it to UI, but in my property I have always this error

Answer (score 0):

as the error says, you can't access the this object because a different thread owns it, so you can invoke that thread using `Invoke(Delegate Method)`
you can check if invoke required using `tempTab.InvokeRequired`

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because u must be doing the different tasks on the same thread like U cannot make a thread go async and update the UI using the same thread.It will cause conflict.because UI thread is the main thread.

You can use BAckground Worker Thread and subsribe its two eventHandlers to your events which you want to work on.. for eg-

```
BackgroundWorker Worker=new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork+=Yorevent which will do the timeTaking Task();
Worker.RunWorkerCompleted+=YOurEvent which will Update your UI after the work is done();
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

RunWorkerAsync() will make your thread go async and work on background
this way it will not cause any thread Error too..

Comment: Good idea, but backgroundWorker is not usefull here, because I need to create a custom usercontrol using ApartmentState.STA