# Progressbar in Waiting Message Form - Error: InvalidOperationException Cross-thread operation not valid - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, cross-thread

I have the the following method to show in a gridview (`dgJEARequests`) a customized selection of items, as you can see from the images. The user will select the items that will send the parameters to the query `whereStatement`. But when many checkboxes (items) are marked or selected, it will take some time to load all the data in the `dgJEARequests`, let's say, 5000 records, or less. So, I decided to add a `WaitProcessing` (a form with a progress bar). When I click the search button `btnSearchSelection`, I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dgJEARequests' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

```
        private void ShowOnlyCustomSelection()
    {
        String whereStatement = "";
        List<String> fieldList = new List<String>();
        string getStatusName = "";
        string _getStatusName = "";

        //loop through all the checkboxes
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (_cbStatus[i].Checked)
            {
                //getStatusName should give all selected options like this: 'New', 'Started', 'Accepted', etc., then pass it to whereStatement
                _getStatusName += ("'" + _cbStatus[i].Text + "'" + ",").TrimEnd();
            }
        }

        //trims the last comma (,)
        getStatusName = _getStatusName.TrimEnd(',');
        //textBox1.Text = _getStatusName.TrimEnd(','); //--->>this is for testing

        ////////////
        if (getStatusName == "" || getStatusName == null)
        {
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not selected your filter(s)!", "Filter Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Build WHERE Statement
            fieldList.Add("RequestStatus.StatusName IN (" + getStatusName + ")");

            if (fieldList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < fieldList.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        whereStatement = fieldList[x];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        whereStatement = whereStatement + " AND " + fieldList[x];
                    }
                }

                //Seach for Requests
                jeaRequests = itServices.getRequestsBySQLStatement(whereStatement);

                //dgJEARequests.DataSource = jeaRequests;
                requestList = new List<ITWebService.Requests>(jeaRequests.ToList());
                dgJEARequests.DataSource = requestList;
                dgJEARequests.ClearSelection();

                lblCountOfRequests.Text = requestList.Count.ToString().ToString() + " requests loaded";

            }
            else
            {
                if (chkMine.Checked)
                {
                    jeaRequests = itServices.getRequestsByAssignedToAndStatusID(JEAUser.UserName, "0");
                    //dgJEARequests.DataSource = jeaRequests;
                    requestList = new List<ITWebService.Requests>(jeaRequests.ToList());
                    dgJEARequests.DataSource = requestList;
                    dgJEARequests.ClearSelection();
                }
                else
                {
                    jeaRequests = itServices.getRequestsBySQLStatement("Requests.ID > 0");
                    //dgJEARequests.DataSource = jeaRequests;
                    requestList = new List<ITWebService.Requests>(jeaRequests.ToList());
                    dgJEARequests.DataSource = requestList;
                    dgJEARequests.ClearSelection();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the `progressbar`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JEAProjectManager
{
    public partial class WaitProcessing : Form
    {
        public Action Worker
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public WaitProcessing(Action worker)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (worker == null)

                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            Worker = worker;

        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                this.Close();
            },
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

This other is for when I click the search button:

```
private void btnSearchSelection_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ShowOnlyCustomSelection();
        //WaitProcessing processing = new WaitProcessing();
        using (WaitProcessing processing = new WaitProcessing(ShowOnlyCustomSelection))
        {
            processing.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

The query parameters are sent to a Webservice. What can I do to solve this problem? I am customizing this application. I am not the original developer, but it is my task to make it better. I know there are some similar errors out there, but different scenarios.

Screenshots:

Doing my selection

[image: Selection]

Passing parameters for query

[image: Parameters]

ProgressBar

[image: ProgressBar]

Error Message

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible duplicate :-/
[How to deal with cross-thread access exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923865/how-to-deal-with-cross-thread-access-exceptions)

you need to ensure, that the access thread is initialized

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer was easy, but took me a while to figure it out. I am not sure if there are better solutions for this, but I had to enclose those components in lambda expression like:

```
lblCountOfRequests.Text = requestList.Count.ToString().ToString() + " requests loaded";
```

Or

```
dgJEARequests.Invoke(new Action(() => dgJEARequests.DataSource = requestList));
```